# Combine multiple grep outputs in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, variable

Basically I have below scenario e.g.

1. `grep 'test: \K(\d+)' $file` => 15
2. `grep 'test1: \K(\d+)' $file` => 20

Is there any way to store result of both commands into a variable like with comma as separator,

```
Test="grep 'test: \K(\d+)' $file;grep 'test1: \K(\d+)' $file"
```

Answer=`eval $Test`

Expected output: `15,20`?

Comment: Maybe `grep -Po 'test1?: \K\d+' < "$file" | paste -sd , -`. The order would be based on where `test` and `test1` occur in the file.

Comment: (btw, ITYM `grep -Po 'test...` above (assuming that's GNU `grep`))

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do that by using *Command substitution*:

```
Test="$(grep 'test: \K(\d+)' $file),$(grep 'test1: \K(\d+)' $file)"
```

The variable=`$(..)` called *Command substitution* and it's means nothing more but to run a shell command and store its output to a variable or display back using `echo` command. For example, display date and time:

```
echo "Today is $(date)"
```

and for store it to a variable:

```
SERVERNAME="$(hostname)"
```

you can concatenate to output:

```
echo "$(hostname),$(date)"
```

the result will be:

```
yourhostname,Tue Jan 24 09:56:32 EET 2017
```

Comment: Edited question. Eval will fail if we use above approach?

Comment: @Rock, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065077/eval-command-in-bash-and-its-typical-uses

Comment: Need more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

To put the output of a command into a variable, use [command substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution), that's exactly what it's for. Using `eval` cannot help (even if you were using it correctly, which [you aren't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)).

```
Test="$(grep 'test: \K(\d+)' "$file"; grep 'test1: \K(\d+)' "$file")"
```

The output is two numbers (assuming that each of the patterns matches exactly once) separated by a newline. The reason they are separated by a newline is that grep outputs lines (like any other tool), and a line always ends with a newline character. The first `grep` prints `15` with a newline at the end, the second `grep` prints `20` with a newline at the end, and then the command substitution strips the newline(s) at the end. If you want a comma as the separator, use two command substitutions, and include the comma in between:

```
Test="$(grep 'test: \K(\d+)' "$file"),$(grep 'test1: \K(\d+)' "$file")"
```